# How can i remove this "ï»¿" from my page

Tags: php

Im building a website in php, and appears this "ï»¿" on the top.

I was searching about this problem, and it is about ISO-8859-1, but i dont want to change my charset to UTF-8 because when i change my charset to UTF-8, all accents disappear.

Is there any way to hide this ""ï»¿"? Changing the colour in php, or using another trick.

I tried to use UTF-8, but it doesnt work, my database table is in latin1_swedish_ci, but the only way to make all the accents appear is using ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Is this appearing on your actual page, or just in your page source when you view it?

Comment: You should always use UTF-8 on the web. Convert your table to utf-8 using http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your code editor set to use BOM.
Change your editor to not use BOM, and make sure you're using a good editor.

Though, for future ref and ease of you and SO, a search on this site or Google for those chars would have led you to that :)